# Alternative to Windows Media Player that supports all video/audio files

Tags: windows, video, audio, media-player

I have been using Windows Media Player in my Windows 7 and I found that it can't play some type of video formats like MKV. So I am searching for a new player which:

- supports any type of video files
- supports any type of audio files
- should be under 30 MB in size
- should provide volume above 100 (because Windows Media Player is not so good in case of volume)
- should be easy to use

Comment: "any type"? I feel you have not much idea about how many video and audio formats exists - hundreds each. Not sure you need all. Computer archaeologists do.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would recommend [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

- it will play just about any video/audio you throw at it (except rmvb)
- it is not under 30mb in size, it's around 100mb (after installation), but this is due to
  it containing all the codecs it needs instead of relying on the
  system codecs - I don't think you will find much improvement here if 
  you count the size that other players would need for codecs while still being able to play everything
- it can provide volume above 100 (up to 200% via scrolling, up to 400%
  via keys)
- it is pretty darn easy to use, and there is a lot of support for the 
  more advanced features.

other positives:

- it's free and open source
- it supports streaming and viewing streams (webcams/etc.)
- it has great subtitle support
- it is highly customizable - you can add/remove buttons to the
  menu/toolbar based on your needs, set the buffering for network
  files, etc.

Comment: How is VLC not under 30 MB ? When I checked to download it, it is just 23.6 MB.

Comment: @ManuJacob: After extracting it, it’s around 100 MB. (Your question didn’t make clear if you are concerned about download size, or size after extracting/installing.)

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.org/). It has the same interface as the old media player in WinXP but plays most video and audio files.

I find MPC-HC is easier to turn subtitles on and off compared to VLC.
It is about 36mb and is open source.

Comment: I found on my old netbook that MPC-HC was less resource intensive then VLC. Where VLC would occasionally stutter when playing back HQ video MPC-HC played it back smoothly.

Comment: also it has a big advantage over VLC: it supports hardware accelerated video decoding

Comment: And it installs codecs on the system for WMP as well, so in case you later wanna play things with WMP, you can.

Comment: @DJDavid98 - MPC has the feature of frame stepping. In options and under `keys` there is an option called Frame step. we can assign a shortcut.

Comment: I use this with Combined Community Codec Pack

Answer (score 1):

My (current) favorite is [GOM Player](http://player.gomlab.com/eng/download/)

Pros

- good built-in codecs
- detects missing codecs and suggests download (rarely needed with its built in support)
- good automatic playlist generator
- equalizer, 100%+ sound volume etc...
- weird settings are hidden
- most common settings can be found in context menu
- free to use

Cons

- weak non-dvd format subtitle support (but they are working on it, ASS got added in last update)
- some controls are different from most of players, eg. double click is play/pause instead of fullscreen on/off. Might be confusing to use for first 10 minutes.

Comment: `double click is play/pause instead of fullscreen` You can change that under `Options > Mouse`.

Answer (score 1):

As @user2813274 stated, VLC is a good program when it comes to 'play anything'.
But as he mentioned, VLC is able to do so thanks to its built-in codecs. Thats not bad, but it's possible to download those codecs separately and use whatever mediaplayer **you want**

I prefer [K-Lite Code Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), but I'm sure there are more of them to be found on the internet.